# how to initialize my function on document ready using trigger etc..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, document-ready

when qololbl mouse click at that time autocomplete function working perfect but how to initialize this function on document ready without qololbl click.

i tried to put this code in document ready $('.qololbl').click() at that time click function working but autocomplete is not working so how to intialize this qololbl click function on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {    

        $(".qololbl").click(function(){
                var garshunivalue = 0;          
                if($('#True').val() == "true")
                {               
                    if($('#defaultgarshuniid').val() > 0)
                    {
                        garshunivalue = $('#defaultgarshuniid').val();
                    }
                }
                $("#qoloname").autocomplete({
                    source: LiveUrl + "/api/Qolo/QoloList?garshunivalue="+garshunivalue,
                    select: function (event, ui) {                  
                        $("#qoloname").val(ui.item.Qolo_Name);                          

                       var searchtype1;
                       if(typeof $('input[name=radio-choice-t-6]:checked').val() == "undefined")
                       {
                           searchtype1 = 'qolo';
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           searchtype1 = $('input[name=radio-choice-t-6]:checked').val();
                       }
                        window.location.href = "index.html?term="+ui.item.Qolo_Name+ "&type=" + searchtype1;                
                    },

                    minLength: 0,
                    close: function(){
                        $(this).blur();
                    }}).focus(function(event, ui){
                        $(this).autocomplete("#stanza", "");
                    }); 

                $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

                    var re = new RegExp($.trim(this.term.toLowerCase()));
                    var qoloname = item.Qolo_Name.replace(re, "<span style='font-weight:600;color:#5C5C5C;'>" + $.trim(this.term.toLowerCase()) + "</span>");
                    var garshuniname = item.Garshuni_Name.replace(re, "<span style='font-weight:600;color:#5C5C5C;'>" + $.trim(this.term.toLowerCase()) + "</span>");
                        return $("<li></li>")
                            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                            .append("<a>"+ "<div style='float:right;'>" + qoloname + "</div>" +"<div style='float:left;'>" + garshuniname + "</div>" + "</a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                };          
            });

            $('.qololbl').click();

    });
```

thanks in advance.

help me

Comment: Have you tried $(".qololbl").trigger('click') on document.ready?

Comment: @KhanjanBhatt Thanks trigger Working For me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crate a separate function for the click event, and then you can call it and also use it for event listener.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
  function initAutocomplete {
    var garshunivalue = 0;
    if ($('#True').val() == "true") {
      if ($('#defaultgarshuniid').val() > 0) {
        garshunivalue = $('#defaultgarshuniid').val();
      }
    }
    $("#qoloname").autocomplete({
      source: LiveUrl + "/api/Qolo/QoloList?garshunivalue=" + garshunivalue,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#qoloname").val(ui.item.Qolo_Name);

        var searchtype1;
        if (typeof $('input[name=radio-choice-t-6]:checked').val() == "undefined") {
          searchtype1 = 'qolo';
        } else {
          searchtype1 = $('input[name=radio-choice-t-6]:checked').val();
        }
        window.location.href = "index.html?term=" + ui.item.Qolo_Name + "&type=" + searchtype1;
      },

      minLength: 0,
      close: function() {
        $(this).blur();
      }
    }).focus(function(event, ui) {
      $(this).autocomplete("#stanza", "");
    });

    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

      var re = new RegExp($.trim(this.term.toLowerCase()));
      var qoloname = item.Qolo_Name.replace(re, "<span style='font-weight:600;color:#5C5C5C;'>" + $.trim(this.term.toLowerCase()) + "</span>");
      var garshuniname = item.Garshuni_Name.replace(re, "<span style='font-weight:600;color:#5C5C5C;'>" + $.trim(this.term.toLowerCase()) + "</span>");
      return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + "<div style='float:right;'>" + qoloname + "</div>" + "<div style='float:left;'>" + garshuniname + "</div>" + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
  }

  $(".qololbl").click(initAutocomplete);
  initAutocomplete();
  //should also work
  //$(".qololbl").trigger('click)

});
```

jQuery `trigger` should also work, are you getting any error when using it?

Comment: Thanks For Response but When I Try Trigger Click That Time Trigger Working For me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
     $(".qololbl").on('click', function(){

})
```

Comment: not on click without any click intialize that whole function. Thanks for response